# What is a domain of automatic testing tools such as ScalaCheck?

Tags: scala, test-automation

I've seen not so many examples of testing with automatic tools, i.e.  serializing/deserializing of JSON (which was paired in the following way:
`val actual = deserialize(serialize(string))`), checking that appending symbols to string was done properly (and that's imho silly, cause it extremely hard to made a mistake in such plain operations).

Can you provide really useful examples/use cases for automatic testing with [ScalaCheck](http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/) that will unveil it advantages? Does it meant to be used mostly in paired style (straight/inverse functions like in JSON example above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the [tests](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/test/files/scalacheck) that Scala itself is using at the moment.

To be honest, I had never seen the kind of paired test you mention. The scope of ScalaCheck is pretty simple: if there's a rule, property, invariant or condition your code must observe, then ScalaCheck is a great fit for it.

I'll state this in reverse to make it even clearer. The only place where you *don't* use ScalaCheck is for code that is composed solely of exceptions -- that is, there is no rule that apply over inputs which will tell you something about the outputs.

There's very few places I can think of where such a thing would happen.